# Does mongodb takes advantage of an index with missing field?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a mongodb collection of `things`, with an existing index `{foo: 1}`

Thanks to the index, the query `db.things.find({foo: 'something'})` is fast, and does not scan documents.

But what about the query `db.things.find({foo: 'something', bar: 'else'})` ?

Intuitively, I'd say that the existing index should help, since it is only required to find the elements matching `foo: 'something'` (fast), and then scan the (hopefully few) documents.

Is this something that mongodb uses, or does it simply ignores the `{foo: 1}` index as the query uses different fields ?

Thanks,

Comment: You can have the query [explained](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to you for that purpose…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct. MongoDB still uses the index even when using other field on the search. You can test it with `db.things.explain().find({foo: 'something', bar: 'else'})`.

You'll get something like:

```
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "filter" : {
            "bar" : {
                    "$eq" : "else"
            }
    },
    "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                    "foo" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "foo_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "foo" : [ ]
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                    "foo" : [
                            "[\"something\", \"something\"]"
                    ]
            }
    }
```

This list shows how mongoDB did your search (It starts from bottom to top). The first stage with "IXSCAN" shows that mongoDB used the index first and then tried to do the rest of the search with "FETCH"